# Graph Subscription Created but Notifications Not Being Sent

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

My GraphServiceClient subscription was created on my user and I receive a successful response:

```
{
  "resource": "users/me@my.domain.com/events",
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "clientState": "baedacff-7b53-4aca-81b8-20f9fff68618",
  "notificationUrl": "https://my.domain.com/notification/listen",
  "expirationDateTime": "2018-04-27T17:57:16.0115964+00:00",
  "id": "f4090189-2d12-45a0-9ad2-77c3595b07b4",
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity"
}
```

However, although the exact same code was working yesterday, today no notifications are sent to my endpoint.

I have no idea what to look at to see why this isn't working as the subscription says it was created, simply O365 is NOT sending any notifications.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Are you receiving the subscription validation request with a `validationToken`?

Comment: Hi Mark, yes, the request is received at /Notification/listen and a token is sent back hence the validation succeeds and I receive the subscription ID.  Despite the same code working recently, the next day I received "GatewayTimeout" and "Service is unavailable" errors which stopped within a few hours as per this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063752/why-does-graphserviceclient-stop-working-and-then-start).  Now, the subscription is validated and created; however, notifications are not being sent like they were before.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue was caused by some sort of throttling done by O365.  We have not experienced it since and we are creating subscriptions for hundreds of users in O365.  If you are creating subscriptions and not getting notifications, I suggest deleting your subscriptions, waiting a day or two and creating them again.