# I have managed to create Subscription for new email arrivals but the Microsoft Graph API is not notifying about it

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have succeeded in creating a Subscription for getting notified about new email arrivals to a specified notification URL. I am receiving a subscription id every time I call the API that creates a subscription. But for some reason, the Graph API is not notifying(notification URL specified in the Subscription object) when I send email to the connected email address.

I admit that at the beginning, I missed to respond properly with HTTP Accepted Status Code to the Graphs notification requests.

I have read this answer but not much suggestions[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50068294/graph-subscription-created-but-notifications-not-being-sent). Any help?

Subscription object

```
    Subscription subscription = new Subscription()
                    {
                        ChangeType = "updated",
                        NotificationUrl = "XXNotificationUrlXX",
                        Resource = "users/" + UserId + "/messages",
                        ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15),
                        ClientState = ClientStateForNewEmail
                    };
```

And Creation Success Response

```
    {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity",
    "id": "7b468a72-f521-43e3-aadc-7133282437f3",
    "resource": "users/{UserId}/messages",
    "applicationId": "XXAppIdXX",
    "changeType": "updated",
    "clientState": "XXClientStateXX",
    "notificationUrl": "XXNotificationUrlXX",
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-07-20T18:27:37.9356913Z",
    "creatorId": "44d82a81-a027-473f-92ac-621108163c94",
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
   }
```

I am using Apps behalf, that's why the: user/{UserId}/messages

Creation Code

```
                    var subrslt = await graphServiceClient.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(subscription).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Notification Url Code:

```
   try
            {
                return _TrialRunService.postrequest(validationToken).Result;//returns Accepted if no error
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    
//Log if any error
                }
                catch {//To Guarantee Accepted Response(in any case) delivery to Graph Api }
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted) { Content = new StringContent("") };
```

I have tried to guarantee Accepted Response to Graph API no matter if there occurs any error from our side.

Comment: I have checked in the list of subscription and I found none.

Comment: Is there any need for deleting the subscriptions? I can't find them in /subscriptions api after they have expired.

Comment: Can you share more code on the subscription creation please? Specifically the part where you execute the request. No you don't need to delete expired subscriptions, they are removed automatically

Comment: @baywet I have used ".Result" is that a problem? Since its an web api I dont think it matters if it runs synchronously or not

Answer (score 1):

Your subscription is on the updated change type. So it'll only be triggered whenever somebody edits an email already existing in the mailbox.
To receive notifications on new emails the change type needs to be "created".

```
Subscription subscription = new Subscription()
{
    ChangeType = "created,updated",
```